# round number to nearest 0.2 with PHP

Tags: php, math, rounding

I'm creating this rating system using 5-edged stars. And I want the heading to include the average rating. So I've created stars showing 1/5ths. Using "1.2" I'll get a full star and one point on the next star and so on...

But I haven't found a good way to round up to the closest .2... I figured I could multiply by 10, then round of, and then run a switch to round 1 up to 2, 3 up to 4 and so on. But that seems tedious and unnecessary...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
round(3.78 * 5) / 5 = 3.8
```

Comment: awesome! I knew there had to be an easy solution to this. Thanks (:

Answer (score 18):

A flexible solution

```
function roundToNearestFraction( $number, $fractionAsDecimal )
{
     $factor = 1 / $fractionAsDecimal;
     return round( $number * $factor ) / $factor;
}

// Round to nearest fifth
echo roundToNearestFraction( 3.78, 1/5 );

// Round to nearest third
echo roundToNearestFraction( 3.78, 1/3 );
```

Comment: Elegant, but you are missing some "$".

Comment: Nice. But since I know that I'll always be needing fraction of 5, there is really no point in creating a general function for it. But I'll def. keep this in mind. Thanks (:

Answer (score 4):

```
function round2($original) {
    $times5 = $original * 5;
    return round($times5) / 5;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So your total is 25, would it be possible to not use floats and use 1->25/25? That way there is less calculations needed... (if any at all)

Comment: +1 - that's a good point, but I'm assuming that the score of 1.2 or 1.17 or whatever is actually an average, so there'll be fractions involved at some point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why is everyone giving solutions that require a deeper inspection or conversion? Want 0.2? Then:

```
round($n / 0.2) * 0.2; // $n = 3.78 / 0.2 = 18.9 (=) 19 * 0.2 = 3.8 //
```

Want 5? Then:

```
round($n / 5) * 5; // $n = 17 / 5 = 3.4 (=) 3 * 5 = 15 //
```

It's as simple as that.

Comment: Because you will get floating point errors with this solution!