# Flexible solution to round number to nearest specified "20-th" multiple taking into account decimal places

Tags: c#, rounding

I'm in need of a flexible way where I can find the closest multiple of "20" taking into account rounding to the (number of decimal places - 1). If there's 0 or 1 decimal places, then the number is rounded to the nearest 20.

And then specify how many multiples of that 20 I want above or below the current number.

For example, if the number is:
1.09426
valid numbers at multiples of ".0020" (5 decimal places - 1) are:
1.10000
1.09800
1.09600
1.09400
1.09200
1.09000
1.08800

So if I say I want 2 above 1.09426, then I should get 1.0980 because "80" is 2 multiples of 20 above "0042" -> 60, 80.

Likewise, if the number is:
1234.5
valid numbers at multiples of "20" are:
1300
1280
1260
1240
1220
1200
1180
1160

Numbers will always be positive.

I thought I had a basic function as follows, but it's obviously not working and I can't figure out how to make it work:

```
public static double GetNext20Num(int numOfDecimalPlaces, int howManyForward, double fractionAsDecimal, double price)
{
    //fractionAsDecimal would be passed in as 1/5 or 0.2
    //howManyForward is how many multiples of "20" above the current price we want. For example, if price is 1234.5 and howManyForward is 2,
    //that means we should return 1260 as 60 is 2 multiples of 20 above 1234 (1240 & 1260)
    double factor = (1 / fractionAsDecimal) * 10 * (100.0 / Math.Pow(10.0, numOfDecimalPlaces));
    double num = Math.Round(price * factor) / factor;
    return num + (double)howManyForward * fractionAsDecimal;
}
```

We looked at a few PHP and Python solutions, such as these:

- [round number to nearest 0.2 with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796450/round-number-to-nearest-0-2-with-php)
- [Java: round to nearest multiple of 5 (either up or down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196987/java-round-to-nearest-multiple-of-5-either-up-or-down)

but they don't quite fit the bill or we haven't been able to adapt successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a formula for figuring out the set of possible values? It seems like you strip off the first digit (which is curiously always 1 in your examples) and then play games with the number that remains. A general rule (expressed mathematically) would help a lot

Comment: @Flydog57 - no. That's what we're looking for with the function is to get the set of values. With teh function, we have the parameter to pass in that we want a particular value "x" values away from the price passed in. With the examples, you can replace all the starting numbers with 2, 3, or 4 and no difference as we still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

We've figured it out.

We've calculated the closest number that ends in "00".

Then we calculate the "factor" to add/subtract by:
(100.0 / Math.Pow(10.0, numberOfDecimalPlaces)) * 2;

Finally we do a loop from the "00" number either backwards or forwards, incrementing by "factor" each iteration until we're at the "howManyForward" we should be.

If there's a formula for doing it all in one go without having to loop, it's not coming to us.